# How to represent a Neo4J GoGM node related to siblings?

Tags: json, go, neo4j, graph-theory

I've create a graph database where a node can be related to other nodes of the same type/label: I could get such nodes by running a simple query like:
`MATCH (n1:Node)-[]-(n2:Node) RETURN n1,n2`

I'm using GoGMv2 to map the Neo4J nodes to their struct counterparts.
The Node GoGM struct would looks like

```
type Node struct {
    // provides required node fields
    gogm.BaseNode

    Name        string        `gogm:"name=name" json:"name"`
    Siblings    []*Node       `gogm:"direction=both;relationship=RELATES_TO" json:"siblings"`
}
```

It's super classic with graphs but the serialization as JSON fails with the Marshal or Encode functions because they can't represent cyclic structs (Marshal returns a value error: `json: unsupported value: encountered a cycle via []*Node`)

Any (re)design or implementation ideas?

EDIT:
So I went ahead and just broke the recursion when marshalling the JSON, by implementing a custom MarshalJSON on the Node struct. Thanks for the few hints (and lively comments)

Answer (score 0):

Give each node a unique index.

Replace

```
Siblings    []*Node
```

with

```
std::vector<int> sibling_index
```

Comment: GoGM is a Go object-graph mapper. Unless I missed a big Go update, `std::vector<int> sibling_index` is not Go code ^^

Comment: Whatever. Use whatever syntax your language needs for a vector of integers.

Comment: Not sure that GoGM annotations allow for plucking to a struct member instead of the struct itself. Will see how I can give it a try

Comment: @ravenspoint it depends specifically on what GoGM supports, not just Golang, so I don't really understand the point you are trying to make.

Comment: @fbiville The point is that the cycles can be broken by using integer indexes rather than pointers.

Comment: @EricM Plucking?

Comment: @ravenspoint if you could point to the section of the GoGM documentation that supports your claim, it would help a lot

Comment: I claim nothing about GoGM.  I am pointing out that the cycles can be broken by using a design with indices rather than pointers.  How many time do you need to be told this?

Comment: If your general advice is not applicable to what GoGM allows, then your answer is basically unhelpful (just like your unfriendly tone).